# Gulp browser sync breaks scss sourcemaps after injection

Tags: gulp, source-maps, browser-sync

First render sourcemaps refer to scss properly, after injection refers to minificated css.
After reloading browser (manually) sourcemaps works properly again.

package.json (last versions of plugins for today)

```
    ...
"devDependencies": {
   "gulp": "^4.0.2",
   "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
   "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
   "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.6.5",
   "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
   "vinyl": "^2.2.0", // used for extraStyleDest path
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
function extStyle () {
  return (
    gulp.src( extraStyleSRC )
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .on("error", sass.logError)
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(extraStyleDest.path))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
  )
}
    
const watch2 = () =>  gulp.watch(
  extraStyleSRC, gulp.series( extStyle )
);

const bs = () => {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: projectURL,
    open: true,
    injectChanges: true,
    port: 8880,
  });
};

const dev = gulp.parallel( bs,  watch2 );

gulp.task( 'dev', dev );
```

Results:
[chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJE99.png)
After injection
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87o6c.png)

Any suggestions to fix without reloading?